# Add created date time to a REST API using Swagger

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

I have a couple of APIs and using `springfox-swagger` for API documentation.
I have a requirement to add the creation date to the respective API. How can I achieve this using `swagger`. I don't need any API versioning.

Ex:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Creates a new user and returns the created user.")
    @PostMapping(/user)
    public ResponseEntity<UserDto> createUser(@RequestBody UserDto userDto) {
        User user =userService.create(userDto);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(UserMappers.USER_ENTITY_TO_DTO.apply(user),HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

In the above example, I want to add the creation date of `/user` so that I can trace the creation date.

Answer (score 0):

In my project I have a similar requirement. As a solution I have created a custom annotation (for marking the endpoint) and wrote a plugin (for updating the API description).

**Option #1**

- `@ApiSince` annotation:

  ```
  @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
  @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
  public @interface ApiSince {
      String value() default "";
  }
  ```
- `ApiSincePlugin` plugin:

  ```
  @Component
  public class ApiSincePlugin implements OperationBuilderPlugin {

      private final DescriptionResolver resolver;

      @Autowired
      public ApiSincePlugin(DescriptionResolver resolver) {
          this.resolver = resolver;
      }

      @Override
      public void apply(OperationContext context) {

          final String sinceTemplate = "### Since %s%n%n%s";
          String notes = "";
          Optional<ApiOperation> apiOperationOptional = context.findAnnotation(ApiOperation.class);
          if (apiOperationOptional.isPresent()) {
              notes = apiOperationOptional.get().notes();
          }
          String finalNotes = notes;
          Optional<ApiSince> apiSinceOptional = context.findAnnotation(ApiSince.class);
          if (apiSinceOptional.isPresent()) {
              finalNotes = String.format(sinceTemplate, apiSinceOptional.get().value(), notes);
          }
          context.operationBuilder().notes(resolver.resolve(finalNotes));
      }

      @Override
      public boolean supports(DocumentationType type) {
          return true;
      }
  }
  ```
- `@ApiSince` in action:

  ```
  @ApiSince(value = "2019-10-31")
  @PostMapping(value = "/login")
  @ApiOperation(value = "Authenticate user", nickname = "login", notes = "your API description")
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
  @ApiResponses(value = {
      @ApiResponse(code = 200, response = LoginResponse.class, message = HTTP_200_OK),
      ...
  })
  @ResponseBody
  ResponseEntity<LoginResponse> login(...);
  ```

  [image]

---

If you don't want do add it in the description but as an extra JSON attribute then take a look at this solution: [Custom Operation Builder Plugin](https://github.com/indrabasak/swagger-deepdive/wiki/Custom-Operation-Builder-Plugin)
.

**Option #2**

- `@ApiSince` annotation (code same as above)
- `ApiSincePlugin` plugin:

  ```
  @Component
  public class ApiSincePlugin implements OperationBuilderPlugin {

      @Override
      public void apply(OperationContext context) {
          Optional<ApiSince> annotation = context.findAnnotation(ApiSince.class);
          if (annotation.isPresent()) {
              String value = annotation.get().value();
              ObjectVendorExtension extention = new ObjectVendorExtension("x-since");
              extention.addProperty(new StringVendorExtension("value", value));
              context.operationBuilder().extensions(Collections.singletonList(extention));
          }
      }

      @Override
      public boolean supports(DocumentationType documentationType) {
          return true;
      }
  }
  ```
- Activate extensions in the Swagger UI:

  ```
  @Bean
  UiConfiguration uiConfig() {
      return UiConfigurationBuilder
              .builder()
              .showExtensions(true)
              ...
              .build();
  }
  ```
- `@ApiSince` in action (code same as above):

  [image]